Groupby and Aggregate based on condition
My input data:
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','C','D'],
                 'Group':['group1','group1','group2','group2'],
                 'Flag_1':[1,0,0,1],
                 'Flag_2':[1,1,0,1],
                 'Value':[30,40,60,70]
                })


I am trying to add up "Value" per group when flag is equal to 1. My expected output is:
df_value_group=pd.DataFrame({
                 'Flag_1 Sum':[1,1],
                 'Flag_2 Sum':[2,1],
                 'Value_1 Sum':[30,70],
                 'Value_2 Sum':[70,70]},                 
    index=['group1','group2'])


I have tried this but it throws me an AssertionError error primarly due to the latter two lambda function.
df.groupby('Group').agg(
    **{ 'Flag_1 Sum': ('Flag_1','sum'),
        'Flag_2 Sum': ('Flag_2','sum'),
        'Value_1 Sum': ('Flag_1', lambda col: df.loc[col.eq(1), 'Value'].sum()),
        'Value_2 Sum': ('Flag_2', lambda col: df.loc[col.eq(1), 'Value'].sum())
})



For a generic approach, you could use a custom groupby.agg (named aggregation):
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Flag_')]
val = df['Value']

out = (df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)
         .agg(**({f'{c} Sum': (c, lambda x: x.sum()) for c in cols}
                |{f'Value{c[4:]} Sum': (c, lambda x: val[x.index][x==1].sum())
                  for c in cols}
                )
             )
      )

NB. lambda x: val[x.index][x==1].sum() could be replaced by lambda x: val.where(x==1).sum().
Or reshape with melt and aggregate with pivot_table:
tmp = (df
   .melt(['ID', 'Group', 'Value'], var_name='flag', value_name='bool')
   .query('bool == 1')
   .pivot_table(index='Group',
                columns='flag',
                aggfunc='sum',
                fill_value=0,
                )
 )

out = (pd.concat([tmp['bool'],
                  tmp['Value'].rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Flag', 'Value'))
                  ], axis=1)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
       )

Output:
    Group  Flag_1  Flag_2  Value_1  Value_2
0  group1       1       2       30       70
1  group2       1       1       70       70


A more efficient form is to compute the booleans before grouping:
flags=df.assign(value_1_sum=df.loc[df.Flag_1.eq(1),'Value'],   
                value_2_sum = df.loc[df.Flag_2.eq(1),'Value'])

flags

  ID   Group  Flag_1  Flag_2  Value  value_1_sum  value_2_sum
0  A  group1       1       1     30         30.0         30.0
1  B  group1       0       1     40          NaN         40.0
2  C  group2       0       0     60          NaN          NaN
3  D  group2       1       1     70         70.0         70.0

flags.groupby('Group').sum(numeric_only=True)
        Flag_1  Flag_2  Value  value_1_sum  value_2_sum
Group
group1       1       2     70         30.0         70.0
group2       1       1    130         70.0         70.0


Create a lambda function with where function
cond1 = df['Flag_1'].eq(1)
cond2 = df['Flag_2'].eq(1)

out = df.groupby('Group').agg(
    **{ 'Flag_1 Sum': ('Flag_1','sum'),
        'Flag_2 Sum': ('Flag_2','sum'),
        'Value_1 Sum': ('Value', lambda x: x.where(cond1).sum()),
        'Value_2 Sum': ('Value', lambda x: x.where(cond2).sum())
})

out:
        Flag_1 Sum  Flag_2 Sum  Value_1 Sum  Value_2 Sum
Group                                                   
group1           1           2           30           70
group2           1           1           70           70


If there are many columns that correspond to the Flag, or if the entire row is long and efficiency is important, it is better to create a groupby for each and then use concat function.
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Flag')]

out = pd.concat([
    df.groupby('Group')[cols].sum().add_suffix(' Sum'),
    df[cols].mul(df['Value'], axis=0)
    .groupby(df['Group']).sum()
    .rename(lambda x: x.replace('Flag', 'Value') + ' Sum', axis=1)
], axis=1)

same result

You want to aggregate over 'Value', not 'Flag_X'
df_value_group = df.groupby('Group').agg(
    **{ 'Flag_1 Sum': ('Flag_1','sum'),
        'Flag_2 Sum': ('Flag_2','sum'),
        'Value_1 Sum': ('Value', lambda x: x[df['Flag_1'] == 1].sum()),
        'Value_2 Sum': ('Value', lambda x: x[df['Flag_2'] == 1].sum())
})

        Flag_1 Sum  Flag_2 Sum  Value_1 Sum  Value_2 Sum
Group                                                   
group1           1           2           30           70
group2           1           1           70           70

